# How to see initial value .Select/Option

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select with the option and a js who make possible to hide and show the content after id and value when I go to all option the code works.
When I select the option with the name "brands name" again. I don't see anything.

[Here the link to the page](https://carsworldro.000webhostapp.com/cars_video.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make a few steps to fix this issue:

1. Add value to option `<option value="showen">Name of the brands</option>`
2. Add new function `toggleContent` for toggle content.
3. Add `toggleContent($("#dropdown").val());` to end of script. This code should display the content after the page is initialized.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function toggleContent(val) {
    $('.loader').fadeIn();
    $(".video").hide();
    $(".showss").hide();
    $("#" + val).hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.loader').fadeOut();
      $("#" + val).show();
    }, 1500);

  }
  $("#dropdown").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    toggleContent(val)
  });

  toggleContent($("#dropdown").val());
});
```

```css
body {
      background-color: #000;
    }
    
    .loader {
      border: 10px solid #fff;
      /* Light grey */
      border-top: 10px solid #3498db;
      /* Blue */
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      position: absolute;
      top: 48%;
      left: 48%;
      display: none;
    }
    
    @keyframes spin {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 475px) {
      .loader-video {
        border: 8px solid #fff;
        /* Light grey */
        border-top: 8px solid #3498db;
        /* Blue */
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        top: 48%;
        left: 48%;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 384px) {
      .loader {
        border: 8px solid #fff;
        /* Light grey */
        border-top: 8px solid #3498db;
        /* Blue */
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        top: 48%;
        left: 48%;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
      .loader {
        border: 8px solid #fff;
        /* Light grey */
        border-top: 8px solid #3498db;
        /* Blue */
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        top: 48%;
        left: 48%;
      }
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group container">
      <select class="form-control" id="dropdown">
        <option value="showen">Name of the brands</option>
        <option value="carsvideo1">Acura</option>
        <option value="carsvideo2">Abarth</option>
        <option value="carsvideo3">Alfa Romeo</option>
        <option value="carsvideo4">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="loader"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 style="color:yellow;" class="showss text-center" id="showen">Main Content</h2>
  </div>
  <!--Hidden Content-->
  <div class="video" id="carsvideo1">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="text-center" style="color:red">Acura Video</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="video" id="carsvideo2">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="text-center" style="color:blue">Abarth Video</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="video" id="carsvideo3">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="text-center" style="color:green">Alfa Romeo Video</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="video" id="carsvideo4">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="text-center" style="color:white">Audi Video</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because "brands name" option has no value to hook up by your JS code. You need to assign some value to "brands name" option and (on change)track if "brands name" selected or not. If so - act accordingly.
I can't say more without your code.

Comment: You can also just disable default option `<option selected disabled>brands name</option>` so it would be impossible to pick it